# If statement with VLookup

Tags: excel, if-statement, vlookup

I am having trouble setting up a function that joins my two sheets on multiple criteria.

I want the following to happen in the flight column:

```
IF sheet1.product = sheet2.product AND
sheet1.date >= sheet2.start date AND
sheet1.date <= sheet2.end date THEN
sheet2.flight
```

I cannot concatenate and vlookup off that because I am looking for a range of dates and I cannot use if(and( because I need my 'value_if_true' to be dynamic.

What is the best formula to achieve what I have tried to explain?

```
Sheet1
For flight column row 1
=IF(AND(D2=Sheet2!A2,Sheet1!A2>=Sheet2!B2,Sheet1!A2<=Sheet2!C2),Sheet2!D2)

Date    Start Date  End Date    product      flight
11/29/2015  11/29/2015  12/5/2015   product1    1
11/29/2015  11/29/2015  12/5/2015   product1    
11/30/2015  11/29/2015  12/5/2015   product1    
11/30/2015  11/29/2015  12/5/2015   product1    
12/1/2015   11/29/2015  12/5/2015   product1    
12/1/2015   11/29/2015  12/5/2015   product1    
12/2/2015   11/29/2015  12/5/2015   product1    
12/3/2015   11/29/2015  12/5/2015   product1    
12/3/2015   11/29/2015  12/5/2015   product1    
12/4/2015   11/29/2015  12/5/2015   product1    
12/5/2015   11/29/2015  12/5/2015   product1    
11/25/2015  11/29/2015  12/5/2015   product2    
11/26/2015  11/29/2015  12/5/2015   product2    
11/27/2015  11/29/2015  12/5/2015   product2    
11/29/2015  11/29/2015  12/5/2015   product2    
11/29/2015  11/29/2015  12/5/2015   product2    
11/30/2015  11/29/2015  12/5/2015   product2    
11/30/2015  11/29/2015  12/5/2015   product2    
12/1/2015   11/29/2015  12/5/2015   product2    
12/1/2015   11/29/2015  12/5/2015   product2    
12/2/2015   11/29/2015  12/5/2015   product2    
12/2/2015   11/29/2015  12/5/2015   product2    
12/3/2015   11/29/2015  12/5/2015   product2    
12/3/2015   11/29/2015  12/5/2015   product2    
12/4/2015   11/29/2015  12/5/2015   product2    
12/4/2015   11/29/2015  12/5/2015   product2    
12/5/2015   11/29/2015  12/5/2015   product2    
12/6/2015   11/29/2015  12/5/2015   product2    

Sheet2
product   start date    end date    flight
product1    11/29/2015  12/1/2015   1
product1    12/2/2015   12/5/2015   2
product2    11/25/2015  11/30/2015  1
product2    12/1/2015   12/2/2015   2
product2    12/3/2015   12/6/2015   3
```

Any help much appreciated. thanks.

---

**Error when changing Column Reference**

Getting #N/A! value not available error when I change the column reference from D to O. Cell references are identical (dataVal dropdown with same source) data below to illustrate. As mentioned in comments, this formula worked perfectly before I made the one change of column D to O.

formula (using Ctrl-Shift-Enter):

=INDEX('flighting schedule'!$F$3:INDEX('flighting       schedule'!F:F,MATCH(1E+99,'flighting schedule'!F:F)),MATCH(1,IF((A2>='flighting     schedule'!$B$3:INDEX('flighting schedule'!B:B,MATCH(1E+99,'flighting     schedule'!F:F)))*(A2<='flighting schedule'!$C$3:INDEX('flighting     schedule'!C:C,MATCH(1E+99,'flighting schedule'!F:F)))*(O2='flighting     schedule'!$A$3:INDEX('flighting schedule'!A:A,MATCH(1E+99,'flighting schedule'!F:F))),1,0),0))

This is the data on the active sheet:

```
Date    ColB    ColC    Start Date   End Date   ColF    ColG    ColH    Coli        ColJ    ColK    ColL    ColM    flight  Product
11/29/2015  Emp Loc 11/29/2015  12/5/2015   Type    ZZZ dim dim 4850000     2015-11 1   1524    #REF!   ProductA
11/29/2015  Emp Loc 11/29/2015  12/5/2015   Type    ZZZ dim dim 4850000     2015-11 691 2046191 #REF!   ProductA
11/30/2015  Emp Loc 11/29/2015  12/5/2015   Type    ZZZ dim dim 4850000     2015-11 3   1906    #REF!   ProductA
11/30/2015  Emp Loc 11/29/2015  12/5/2015   Type    ZZZ dim dim 4850000     2015-11 1152    2923570 #REF!   ProductA
12/1/2015   Emp Loc 11/29/2015  12/5/2015   Type    ZZZ dim dim 4850000     2015-12 2   3   #REF!   ProductA
12/1/2015   Emp Loc 11/29/2015  12/5/2015   Type    ZZZ dim dim 4850000     2015-12 0   49  #REF!   ProductA
12/2/2015   Emp Loc 11/29/2015  12/5/2015   Type    ZZZ dim dim 4850000     2015-12 0   2   #REF!   ProductA
12/3/2015   Emp Loc 11/29/2015  12/5/2015   Type    ZZZ dim dim 4850000     2015-12 0   433 #REF!   ProductA
12/3/2015   Emp Loc 11/29/2015  12/5/2015   Type    ZZZ dim dim 4850000     2015-12 642 2002431 #REF!   ProductA
12/4/2015   Emp Loc 11/29/2015  12/5/2015   Type    ZZZ dim dim 4850000     2015-12 2   24  #REF!   ProductA
```

This is the data on 'flighting schedule'

```
Product  start date  end date       Budget      Rate Flight
ProductA    11/29/2015  11/30/2015  $10,000.00  $5.00   1
ProductA    12/01/2015  12/03/2015  $10,000.00  $5.00   2
ProductA    12/04/2016  12/06/14    $10,000.00  $5.00   3
```

Comment: Don't understand why `if`+`and` don't work.

Comment: I believe you when you say it doesn't work. The point is why. Post some data that explains why.

Comment: I am doing this for a large table.  the formula =IF(AND(D2=Sheet2!A2,Sheet1!A2>=Sheet2!B2,Sheet1!A2<=Sheet2!C2),Sheet2!D2) works if I am only looking at one cell but I need it to look at a range which I why I feel that I need a vlookup. I can't attach an example workbook can I?

Comment: It's best to post data as text but if need be, picture works too.

Comment: You likely need `index/match` and perhaps array. If only @scott craner was here ^_^;

Comment: So what happens if no criteria matches as in first line?

Comment: @findwindow when you are trying to summon me, you need to do my name without the space or it does not send me the message.  But see below.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What you want is an Array formula then:

```
=INDEX(Sheet2!$D$2:INDEX(Sheet2!D:D,MATCH(1E+99,Sheet2!D:D)),MATCH(1,IF((A2>=Sheet2!$B$2:INDEX(Sheet2!B:B,MATCH(1E+99,Sheet2!D:D)))*(A2<=Sheet2!$C$2:INDEX(Sheet2!C:C,MATCH(1E+99,Sheet2!D:D)))*(D2=Sheet2!$A$2:INDEX(Sheet2!A:A,MATCH(1E+99,Sheet2!D:D))),1,0),0))
```

Being an array formula one must use Ctrl-Shift-Enter when done editing the formula instead of Enter or Tab.  If done correctly Excel will put `{}` around the formula.

Array formulas calculations are exponential so we want to limit the formula to the extents of the data.  that is what all the `INDEX(Sheet2!D:D,MATCH(1E+99,Sheet2!D:D))` are doing.  They find the last cell in column D that has a number and sets that as the bottom reference automatically.  So as the table on Sheet 2 grows or contracts so does the reference, using only the calculations that are necessary.

[image]

Comment: ++Nice `Sheet2!$B$2:INDEX(Sheet2!B:B,MATCH(1E+99,Sheet2!D:D))`

Comment: Sigh. I understand the gist of it but 5 min later, I forget it all ;_;

Comment: This formula has been working beautifully. I changed the reference in the final Index match beginning after the final * 'D2=Sheet2!$A$2' from D2 to O2 because I need to match the values in column O instead of D...simple enough, just change the column D to O but I'm getting #N/A. The formula is identical except that I changed D to O. The values in Sheet2 are in the same location and are the same value the only difference is that the lookup column on the main sheet has changed from D to O. Is there any basic QA that you recommend for array formulas or match/index?  Thanks. @Scott Craner

Comment: @Nick did you remember the Ctrl-Shift-Enter after editing the formula?

Comment: I am using Ctrl-Shift-Enter. the issue must be somewhere further upstream, I'll continue to dissect. Thanks.

Comment: @Nick Make sure that there are no extra spaces or other unprintable characters in the data and lookups.  This is looking for exact matches.